# Defining membership rule in prolog

Tags: prolog

Currently I am studying prolog programming. While I am studying member list (if element is there on list)it show an error when I am consulting.

```
?- 
Warning: c:/users/h.m.thaheed/pictures/snippingtool++/uploads/exx.pl:1:
Singleton variables: [R]
Warning: c:/users/h.m.thaheed/pictures/snippingtool++/uploads/exx.pl:2:
Singleton variables: [Y]
```

Rule has follows:

```
member(X,[X|R]).
member(X,[Y|R]) :- member(X,R).
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: It's not showing an error, it's showing warnings. And what exactly is it about those warnings that you don't understand?

Comment: Oh. Thanks for help. I thought it is an error. Appreciate your promptly response.

Comment: I would definitely not get in the habit of ignoring singleton variable warnings in Prolog. In this case it is harmless (replace `R` and `Y` with `_`) but it usually suggests a big misunderstanding.

Comment: ^^^ or a code-breaking typo. If you still want to use the mnemonic names, just prepend them with `_`, like `_R` or `_Y`. Such names won't generate the singleton variable warnings.

Comment: I also confused about in this case. I thought that is an error. Because I am new to prolog. However I must be thankful for specially those who response by comments and alternative answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are *not* errors, but warnings. The Prolog interpreter warns that it can only find *one* occurrance of one or more variables, which is strange, since typically variables are used to perform unification, pass values from one predicate to another, etc.

Defining a variable a single time makes only sense as a *placeholder*: when you *need* to specify a variable to perform correct unification. But Prolog has a standardized way to do that: with an underscore `_`. You can see an underscore as a "throw away variable". If a predicate contains two (or more) underscores, then those are *two* (different) variables. The purpose of the underscores is to make it clear that this is a placeholder, and it will thus suppress the warning.

You can thus rewrite the predicate to:

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|R]) :- member(X,R).
```

Note that many implementations of `member/2` use a `member/3` helper predicate to avoid unpacking each "cons" (list element) twice, for example in [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#member/2) we see:

> ```
> member(El, [H|T]) :-
>     member_(T, El, H).
>
> member_(_, El, El).
> member_([H|T], El, _) :-
>     member_(T, El, H).
> ```

So here we unpack the list in parameters of the predicate call. This means that the first clause and the second clause of `member_` do not need to perform unpacking in the head (we here make some assumptions as to how the interpreter exactly works of course), and in the last clause of `member_`, we only unpack the next cons once.